# Excel VBA code to set values on Sheet2 when Macro button is clicked on Sheet1

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have the code attached below. It works when I place a Button(With VBA code) on Sheet2 and run it. However, I wish to place the button on Sheet1 but at the same time make changes on Sheet2.

```
Sub SaveData()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim Rng As Range
    For Each Rng In Range("J8:AS78")
        If Rng.Value > 0 Then
            Rng.Value = Rng.Value
        End If
    Next Rng
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Please help me fix this code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify sheet you want to operate on.  This `Range("J8:AS78")` refers to currently active sheet

Try this

```
Option Explicit 

Sub SaveData()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Ws as worksheet 

    ' change to "sheet2" or whatever name your second sheet has. 
    Set Ws = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Your sheet name") 
    With Ws 
        For Each Rng In .Range("J8:AS78")
            If Rng.Value > 0 Then
                Rng.Value = Rng.Value
            End If
        Next Rng
    End with 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```